# Copy an abstract class without modifying it

Tags: c++

I have an access to an external library that provides a function that returns a pointer to an abstract class Foo, I want to copy that class but the library is pre-compiled so I cannot add any new functions like the virtual clone function https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Virtual_Constructor.

Is there any other way to copy the contents of the pointer?

```
class Foo // private precompiled class I cannot add methods to 
{
    virtual void F() = 0;
};
class FooChild : public Foo
{
    void F() override
    {
        
    }
};
static Foo* getFoo()
{
    return new FooChild();
};


int main()
{
    
    Foo* f = getFoo();
    Foo* fCopy = new Foo(f); //cannot do that
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The correct way would be a virtual `clone` method, else, you might still `dynamic_cast` to each possible case to do the duplication manually :/

Comment: `fCopy = new Foo(f)` is not possible if `Foo` is abstract, since an abstract class cannot be instantiated (whether using a library or not).  One option would be to look in library docs for a means to copy objects that have been created by the library.  If the library doesn't offer that, you probably need to hard-code logic (e.g. using `typeid(*f)` or `dynamic_cast<>` to work out actual type of an object and create a copy).  Note - if a library (particularly a DLL) provides a function to  dynamically create an object, objects/pointers often need to be passed back to the library to destroy them.

Comment: the "contents of the pointer" are just the pointer and you can do that with `Foo* fCopy = f;`, but I'm sure you meant to copy the thing it points to

Answer (score 3):

Your only option is a long `if` `else` `if` chain, based on `typeid(*f)`, with a branch for every possible type.

```
Foo *copy = nullptr;
if (typeid(*f) == typeid(FooChild))
    copy = new FooChild(static_cast<FooChild &>(*f));
else if // ... same for every child class
```

Comment: Why no `if (auto const fooChild = dynamic_cast<FooChild *>(f))`?

Comment: @Quentin Then, if you have more than one inheritance level, you risk slicing because you messed up branch order or forgot a type.

Comment: Very good point indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not forced to use `Foo` in your `main()` there's a way to make this work if you use a `FooBase` subclass instead.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class FooBase: public Foo
{
public:
    virtual FooBase* clone() = 0;
};

template <class Derived>
class FooBase_: public FooBase {
public:
    FooBase* clone() override { return new Derived(static_cast<Derived&>(*this)); }
};

class FooChild1: public FooBase_<FooChild1> {
public:
    FooChild1() = default;
    FooChild1(const FooChild1&) = default;
    void f() override { std::cout << "FooChild1\n"; }
};

class FooChild2: public FooBase_<FooChild2> {
public:
    FooChild2() = default;
    FooChild2(const FooChild2&) = default;
    void f() override { std::cout << "FooChild2\n"; }
};


int main()
{
    
    FooBase* f1 = new FooChild1;
    FooBase* f1Copy = f1->clone();
    f1->f();
    f1Copy->f();

    FooBase* f2 = new FooChild2;
    f2->f();

    delete f1;
    delete f1Copy;
    delete f2;

    return 0;
}
```

`FooBase_` is a CRTP generating a specific `clone()` method for each `FooChildN` concrete class, avoiding repetition.

Demo here: https://godbolt.org/z/nva75Gx4x

Comment: CRTP can be changed in *decorator* for classes which already inherit from `Foo`.